# Is this considered a stable sort method?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

Currently trying to create a merge sort and I believe it's missing something to be stable.
compare.js

```
function compare(left, right) {
  return left - right;
}
```

My code so far:

```
function merge(compare, left, right) {
  let sorted = [];

  while (left.length && right.length) {
    const comparison = compare(left[0], right[0]);

    if (comparison < 0) {
      sorted.push(left.shift());
    } else {
      sorted.push(right.shift());
    }
  }
  return sorted.concat(left, right);
}

function sort(compare, elements) {
  if (Array.isArray(elements)) {
    if (elements.length <= 1) {
      return elements;
    }

    const middle = Math.floor(elements.length / 2);

    const leftElements = elements.slice(0, middle);
    const rightElements = elements.slice(middle);

    const leftSorted = sort(compare, leftElements);
    const rightSorted = sort(compare, rightElements);

    return merge(compare, leftSorted, rightSorted);
  }
  return elements;
}
```

My input:

```
[
  { firstName: "b", lastName: "c" },
  { firstName: "a", lastName: "b" },
  { firstName: "a", lastName: "a" },
  { firstName: "c", lastName: "b" },
  { firstName: "b", lastName: "b" },
  { firstName: "a", lastName: "c" },
]
```

After running the code, this is what's returned.

```
[
  { firstName: 'a', lastName: 'a' },
  { firstName: 'b', lastName: 'b' },
  { firstName: 'c', lastName: 'b' },
  { firstName: 'a', lastName: 'b' },
  { firstName: 'a', lastName: 'c' },
  { firstName: 'b', lastName: 'c' }
]
```

My result is close but my first name values are a little of.
What I should receive:

```
[
  { firstName: "a", lastName: "a" },
  { firstName: "a", lastName: "b" },
  { firstName: "c", lastName: "b" },
  { firstName: "b", lastName: "b" },
  { firstName: "b", lastName: "c" },
  { firstName: "a", lastName: "c" },
]
```

Am I missing an edge case?

Comment: Your compare is only for numeric values. Use `localeCompare()` for strings

Comment: @Cid Just updated the post

Comment: Also you don't seem to be defining a property that needs to be used to determine which  values to sort

Comment: `merge` needs to `sorted.push(left.shift())` when two items are equal. In other words, change `comparison < 0` to `comparison <= 0`

Comment: @user3386109 That's it! Thank you, I appreciate it.

Comment: @user3386109 Please don't post answers as comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mergesort is a stable sort algorithm but your implementation is not stable because of a small mistake in the `merge` function: `if (comparison < 0)` selects the element from the right half instead of the left half if these elements compare equal. You should instead write:

```
    if (comparison <= 0) {
        sorted.push(left.shift());
    } else {
        sorted.push(right.shift());
    }
```